# Create a variable by indexing the colours vector with another variable

Tags: r, indexing, colors

Working with RStudio and I need to know about color indexing into another variable. I put my code with comments. My question is about the last part.

```
# Create a sequential colour scheme with 7 colours using
# the RColorBrewer package. Use any sequential colour scheme
# with 7 colours from the colorbrewer2.org website. Store
# the colour scheme in a variable called map_colours 

map_colours <- c("#8dd3c7", "#ffffb3", "#bebada", "#fb8072", "#80b1d3", "#fdb462", "#b3de69")

# Create a variable called log_change:
 log_change <- c(6055, 12785, 745, -455, 2890, 171990, 70, 21000, 820, 4830, 133315)

# Use the colour_numbers <- cut(log_change) and to divide the
#log_change vector into 6 divisions, set the labels = FALSE, and 
# store the result in #a variable called colour_numbers 

colour_numbers <- cut(log_change, breaks= 6, labels= FALSE)

# To deal with the NA value, I set the 4th value to 0 and then
# add 1 to every value 

colour_numbers[4] <- 0
colour_numbers <- colour_numbers + 1
```

Here is my question: How to create a variable called census_colours by indexing the colours vector with the colour_numbers variable

Comment: I get _"Error: object 'pop_projections' not found"_ when running your code - please provide a reproducible example as asked by the R tag (hover over it). Thanks.

Comment: `map_colours[colour_numbers]`. That's how you would do it. But you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I edited the code and put random numbers. Does it work now? Sorry I am very new in R